# Upgrading SQLite 3.24+ on Ubuntu for use with Python3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I am developing a Python app on MacOS which requires SQLite 3.24 or above. I ran into a problem where the Python `sqlite3` lib was using an old version of SQLite. I managed to fix this relatively pain free but did not note down what I actually did (I didn't have to build anything from source; I think I just updated something).

I am now trying to deploy the app on Ubuntu 18.04 and I am running into the same problem. I cannot seem to fix it despite hours of googling and trying various things.

The SQLite on Ubuntu refuses to go higher then 3.22, so the answer might be I simply have to update the system SQLite *somehow* and Python should pick that up. However, when running `sqlite3` on my Mac, it reports `SQLite version 3.19.3` whereas importing sqlite3 from Python reports `3.28.0` when running `sqlite3.sqlite_version`.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Is my Ubuntu version incapable of installing SQLite 3.24 or above and therefore its impossible? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like you updated the sqlite shared library, but not the sqlite3 executable.

Comment: I think you're right, but I cant get any updates to work on Ubuntu

Comment: I compile from source with all the extra options I use and install into the default /usr/local prefix and it all works.

Comment: I can try that. Are you using Ubuntu 18.04 or lower? Does Python then use that version?